# Multiplying Values of Drop Down and Radio List to Show in Text Box?

Tags: asp.net

I have a Point Table like below that has Drop Down list and 2 Radio Button Lists. After selecting values I would like to show the multipled values and a total of the sections in each Text Box.

For example

DDL1*RB1*RB2 = (THE VALUE1)

DDL2*RB3*RB4 = (THE VALUE2)

Total: (THE VALUE1) + (THE VALUE2)

Example.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<br />
<h3 style="text-align: center">Point Table</h3>
<br />  
    <table style="width:100%;">            
         <tr>
            <td style="width:73px;">Section</td>
            <td style="width:145px;">WEIGHTED SCORE(A)</td>
            <td>FIELD(B)</td>
            <td>FIELD(C)</td>
            <td>FIELD(D) D=AxBxC</td>
        </tr>               
         <tr>               
            <td style="width: 73px">Section A</td>
             <td style="width: 145px">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="80px">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>                
             <td>
                 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" Height="16px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="270px">
                     <asp:ListItem Value="0,4"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="0,7"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                 </asp:RadioButtonList>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server" Height="23px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="383px">
                     <asp:ListItem Value="0,6"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="0,7"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="0,8"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="0,9"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                 </asp:RadioButtonList>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="63px"></asp:TextBox>
             </td>              
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 73px">
                Section B</td>
            <td style="width: 145px">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="80px">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList3" runat="server" Height="16px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="270px">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0,4"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0,7"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList4" runat="server" Height="23px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="383px">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0,6"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0,7"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0,8"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0,9"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="63px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 73px">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 145px">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:73px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width:145px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="text-align:right">TOTAL FIELD:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="63px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>           
    </table>
```

Comment: Do you want to do it on client-side or server-side? On server-side, you can get values like DropDownList1.SelectedValue and RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue. You will have to split the RB Values to get the point coordinates.

Comment: I want to do it on server-side. How may i split the RB values? Each one of them has ID number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to post data, there are many ways.
 
example.aspx 
setting the autopostback property

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server" Height="23px" 
                 RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="383px" AutoPostBack="True">
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0,6"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0,7"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0,8"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0,9"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList4" runat="server" Height="23px" 
                RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="383px" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0,6"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0,7"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0,8"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0,9"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

example.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

        }
        else { 
            UpdateTotals();
        }

    }
    protected void UpdateTotals()
    {
        decimal multiply=0m;
        decimal multiply2=0m;
        //you have to check the value
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue != "Select" && RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue != "" && RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue != "")
        {
            multiply = Decimal.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue) * Decimal.Parse(RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue) * Decimal.Parse(RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue);
            TextBox1.Text = multiply.ToString();
        }

        if (DropDownList2.SelectedValue != "Select" && RadioButtonList3.SelectedValue != "" && RadioButtonList4.SelectedValue != "")
        {
            multiply2 = Decimal.Parse(DropDownList2.SelectedValue) * Decimal.Parse(RadioButtonList3.SelectedValue) * Decimal.Parse(RadioButtonList4.SelectedValue);
            TextBox2.Text = multiply2.ToString();
        }
        TextBox3.Text = string.Format("{0}", multiply + multiply2);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How may i integrate this to code behind? Is it possible to use such a thing inside Example.aspx.cs?


protected void UpdateTotals(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        if (DropDownList1.Visible = true)
        {            
            decimal multiply = Decimal.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue) *
                               Decimal.Parse(RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue) *
                               Decimal.Parse(RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue);
                          
            TextBox1.Text = multiply.ToString();
        }
        
        }

Comment: Thank you so much Tyress. But when applying code behind i'm having an error that says asp.net error CS0123: "No overload matches delegate 'System.EventHandler' for 'UpdateTotals'"

http://pastebin.com/6D2Pww1k

Comment: Okay Tyress by removing OnSelectedIndexChanged="UpdateTotals" the error has fixed. Now it's working. I'm so grateful to you. Thank you so so much.